# Remove 'Continue Shopping' link from WP e-commerce Notification Box

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I am using the WP e-commerce plugin on my site. After you click to the "Add to Cart" button it shows a Fancy notification Box with 2 links:

- Go to checkout
- Continue Shopping

I have only one product on my shop so the "Continue Shopping" link in the Fancy Notification Box become redundant.

Inspecting the element with Firebug it appears to be a jquery that controls the "Continue Shopping" link:

```
<a href=#" onclick="jQuery("#fancy_notification").css("display", "none"); return false;" class="continue_shopping">
```

At this point, how to disable that link? via CSS? if yes, how?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the button with this css :

```
.continue_shopping {
    display: none;
}
```

If you want to remove the link with javascript and jQuery :

```
$(function() {
    $('.continue_shopping').remove();
});
```

Comment: yes, I have tried this option but adding that instruction in css do not change the fact that the link is still there!...

Comment: It's the only way to remove an element with CSS. But i edited my answer with a javascript solution.

Comment: My purpose is actually to remove the link since "continue shopping" on a shop with a single product does not make much sense. 

As a first attempt I have tryed the diplay: none; option but the CSS instruction in that format does not work. 

This is why I addressed the request to a developer's community :)

Comment: thanks Magus. Can you tell me in which file/where in it do I have to add that instruction?

I am not a developer but I am doing my best! :)

Comment: I don't know WP. So i can't tell you in which file you can put that.

Comment: Could you not just stick it in the header.php in your theme folder? Something like: 
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    $('.continue_shopping').remove();
    });
    </script>

Comment: Hi John, I have tried your suggestion but the link it's still there... :)